# Étale cohomology and normalization?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

I have an argument, which I wonder if someone could check:

Let $X$ be an irreducible reduced scheme over a field $k$. Then we have a normal scheme $X^{norm}$ with a finite birational $f:X^{norm}\rightarrow X$. Then for any étale sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, the higher direct image $R^if_*\mathcal{F}$ vanishes for $i>0$. In particular, the Lerray spectral sequence yields
$$H^p_{ét}(X,f_*\mathcal{F})=H^p_{ét}(X^{norm},\mathcal{F}).$$
However, I would like understand $H^i_{ét}(X,\mathbb{Z}/n)$ and relate it to the cohomology of $X^{norm}$, and unfortunatley $f_*(\mathbb{Z}/n)\neq \mathbb{Z}/n$. Hence my question is

Is there a good way to relate the $\ell$-adic cohomology of a scheme with the $\ell$-adic cohomology of its normalization?

Comment: I'm afraid that this result is not true (it fails for e.g. a nodal curve. One way to see this is to compute the singular cohomology over $\mathbb{C}$.) The issue is that the math.SE link you give is only for the Zariski topology, not the etale topology (see the comment of Roland.)

Comment: Ah, good, that makes sense, thank you. Is there a way to relate the $\ell$-adic cohomology of the normalization of a curve with the $\ell$-adic cohomology of the curve itself?

Comment: The best way would be to understand the cokernel of the map.  $\mathbb Z/n \to f_* \mathbb Z/n$. This is supported in the closed subset of $X$ where the fiber of $f$ is disconnected. So a first step would be to identify that closed subset.

Comment: So, for example, if the closed subset wher $f$ is disconnected is a single point for instance, that would imply that for $i\geq 2$, we would have $H^i_{ét}(X,\mathbb{Z}/n)=H^i_{ét}(X^{norm},\mathbb{Z}/n)$, right?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is actually an equivalence for étale cohomology between X and its absolute weak normalization.  That's because the map $X^{awn}\to X$ induces an equivalence of étale ∞-toposes.  Over a field of characteristic $0$, this is the seminormalization, and over a field of characteristic $p>0$, it is the perfection.  I think in general this is the best you can do.

Comment: Why say "$\infty$-topos" when you can just say "site"?